# EPPlus set workbook to SHARED

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

I want to set my workbook to shared at the time of it's creation using the EPPlus library.  Is this possible?  I have found no resource showing me how to do this.  I thought maybe this property would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var package = new ExcelPackage();
package.Workbook.Properties.SharedDoc = true;
```